# Can I make a spectral noise gate with the web audio API?

Tags: html5-audio

Is there a way to specify using the HTML5 web audio API a node that significantly reduces (or even silences) noise that falls within a certain frequency range and that falls under a certain amplitude?

I've noticed biquadfilters and other filters, but they don't seem to consider amplitude of the noise.